# React App UI Isn't Updating After `sortAlphabetically` Function is Run

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app that displays a grid of cars that I'd like to be able to sort on the click of a button.

While I have `this.setState` implemented towards the end of the `sortAlphabetically` function, it isn't being reflected on the web page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CarCard from '../components/CarCard';
import CarForm from './CarForm';
import './Cars.css';
import { getCars } from '../actions/cars';
import { sortCar } from '../actions/cars';

Component.defaultProps = {
  cars: { cars: [] }
}

class Cars extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        cars: [],
        sortedCars: []
      };
  }

sortAlphabetically = () => {
    console.log("sort button clicked")
    const newArray = [].concat(this.props.cars.cars)
    const orgArray = newArray.sort(function (a,b) {
      var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
      var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      } else if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      } 
      return 0;
    }, () => this.setState({ cars: orgArray }))  
    console.log(orgArray)
    this.props.sortCar(orgArray);
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCars()
    this.setState({cars: this.props.cars})
}


render() {
    return (
    <div className="CarsContainer">
        <h3>Cars Container</h3> 
            <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetically}>Sort</button>
            {this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}  
            {/* {this.state.cars.cars && this.state.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}           */}
            <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    cars: state.cars
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    sortCar: (cars) => dispatch(sortCar(cars)),
    getCars: (cars) => dispatch(getCars(cars))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cars);
```

Looking in the console, the `orgArray` does in fact alphabetize the array. The problem is, the UI isn't updating because of some disconnect between props and state.

Why is mapStateToProps not bridging the two together so that a change in the array re-runs render?

Comment: newArray.sort does not mutate the array, It returns a new one (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You need need to reassign it too. And the setState has to be without quotes

Comment: There's 1) nothing in your render that makes references to your new `sortedCars` array and 2) You're setting `sortedCars` to a string.

Comment: fixed the string reference, but how would I implement the `sortedCars` in the `render()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see updated changes, you have to read "cars" from the state instead of reading it from the props.

```
{this.state.cars && this.state.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}
```

Comment: I commented out my line that was reading from props and added yours, but none of the car objects appeared in the UI - do you know what may have caused that? (I tried adding another `.cars` to each `this.state.cars` to match what it was like in my props)

Comment: yes initially you have all your cars in props.
If you want you can set state on componentdidmount
`componentDidMount() {
this.setState({cars: this.props.cars});
}`
Or you can use `static gerDerivedStateFromProps()`

Comment: I'm still getting the same result unfortunately. I don't know why state isn't getting picked up.

Comment: What's strange is that Props > cars is empty in my React dev tools

Comment: Sorry its very difficult to tell what is wrong. 
I have no idea what `getCars()` does.

Comment: No need to apologize. `getCars()` is a redux reducer that fetches cars from my Rails API

Comment: does it also populate "cars" in redux state?

Comment: Cars isn't alphabetized in redux, but console.log(orgArray) shows the alphabetized array.